# Need to count the total sum of operations from 15th day to 15th day of next month

Tags: python, pandas

I need to sum values from floating dates for every period since 15th day of month, for ex. 15.10-14.11, 15.11-14.12 etc. grouped for each pair of `id`-`dp_id`.

My `df`:

```
  date        id      dp   value
  2020-11-13  300000  002  500,00  
  2020-11-14  352575  001  400,00
  2020-11-15  352575  001  100,00
  2020-11-16  352575  001  500,00
  ...............................
      `days from 17.11-12.14`
  ...............................
  2020-12-15  300000  002  700,00
  2020-12-16  352575  001  200,00
  2020-12-17  352575  001  500,00
  2020-12-18  352575  002  600,00
```

**Expected output table**, but not strict variant:
it doesn't matter how to mark this periods in output
for ex 2020-11-01 could mean 15.10-14.11

```
  period      id      dp   value
  2020-11-01  300000  002  500,00  
  2020-11-01  352575  001  400,00
  2021-11-01  352575  002  1000,00
  2020-12-01  300000  002  700,00
  2020-12-01  352575  001  700,00
  2020-12-01  352575  002  600,00
  ...............................
```

I've tried to solve the problem through grouper method, but it doesnt's work for me

```
def grouper(x):
   d = x.rename('date').to_frame().reset_index()
   return d.groupby(pd.Grouper(key='date', freq='M', origin='start')).cumsum()

df['sum'] = df.groupby(['id', 'dp'])['date'].transform(grouper)
```

Comment: 25th to 24th? or 25th to 25th?

Comment: Not calendar month, from 15th day of the month to 14th of next month including, sorry

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you need to create a column that has the year and month. The year and month has to be based on 15th of month to 14th of month. Any value from 15th to 31st should fall under the next month. To do that, use `pd.DateOffset(months=1)` to increment the value to next month. You can use `df.date.dt.day` to get the day part of the date. Check if it is greater than `14`. If so, move the month by 1.

Now that you have the year-month in another column, use that to groupby. If you want each row to have the value, use groupby.transform(). If you want the summary only, then use .sum().

Here's the code to get you the sum for each row.

```
c = ['date','id','dp','value']

d = [['2020-11-13',  300000,  '002',  500.00],  
  ['2020-11-14',  352575,  '001',  400.00],
  ['2020-11-15',  352575,  '001',  100.00],
  ['2020-11-16',  352575,  '001',  500.00],
  ['2020-12-15',  300000,  '002',  700.00],
  ['2020-12-16',  352575,  '001',  200.00],
  ['2020-12-17',  352575,  '001',  500.00],
  ['2020-12-18',  352575,  '002',  600.00]]

import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame(d,columns=c)

df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'])

df['Year-Mon'] = df.date.dt.strftime('%Y-%m')

#
df.loc[df.date.dt.day > 14, 'Year-Mon'] = (df.date + pd.DateOffset(months=1)).dt.strftime('%Y-%m')

df['sum'] = df.groupby(['id', 'dp', 'Year-Mon'])['value'].transform('sum')
print (df)
```

The output of this will be:

```
        date      id   dp  value Year-Mon    sum
0 2020-11-13  300000  002  500.0  2020-11  500.0
1 2020-11-14  352575  001  400.0  2020-11  400.0
2 2020-11-15  352575  001  100.0  2020-12  600.0
3 2020-11-16  352575  001  500.0  2020-12  600.0
4 2020-12-15  300000  002  700.0  2021-01  700.0
5 2020-12-16  352575  001  200.0  2021-01  700.0
6 2020-12-17  352575  001  500.0  2021-01  700.0
7 2020-12-18  352575  002  600.0  2021-01  600.0
```

Answer (score 1):

IIUC, here is one alternative:

```
df['custom_period'] = (df.index.day == 15 - 1).cumsum()  # Begin on every 15th
df['value'] = df.groupby(['custom_period', 'id', 'dp'])['value'].transform('cumsum')
df.drop('custom_period', axis=1, inplace=True)
```

Output:

```
                id  dp  value
date                         
2020-11-13  300000   2    500
2020-11-14  352575   1    400
2020-11-15  352575   1    500
2020-11-16  352575   1   1000
2020-12-15  300000   2    700
2020-12-16  352575   1   1200
2020-12-17  352575   1   1700
2020-12-18  352575   2    600
```

Comment: close to true, but i need sum of 'value' column only, for each pair 'id'-'dp'. in your case we got a sum of each column

Comment: Not sure I got it, but I've added a few tweaks. The mask was off by one day. Is that what you had in mind?